# Accept Cookies — ad nauseam

Tags: bug

About once a week, I'm presented with the "Your Privacy" popup. It gives me the option to customize settings or accept all cookies... I've customized the cookie options, and accepted all at different times, but it keeps popping up.

- I'm using the same browser (Safari)
- Even when I'm auto logged in it pops up

Comment: Does this only happen on Graphic Design or also on other SE sites? In the latter case, you’ll probably get a better answer on [meta.se].

Comment: I’ve only noticed it on GD, but I haven’t been on the others much recently...

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/362091/215485